# fopen() fails but seems to not return NULL?

Tags: c, debugging

I have got the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "config.h"
#include <errno.h>

char buffer[50];
long long bufSize = 50;
FILE* fptr;

char* readConfig(char* buffer, size_t bufSize) {
    fptr = fopen("config.txt", "rt");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        return "error opening config file: %s", strerror(errno);
    } else {
        if ((fgets(buffer, bufSize, fptr)) == NULL) {
            fclose(fptr);
            return "error reading config file: %s", strerror(errno);
        }
        else {
            fclose(fptr);
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

For test purposes I deleted the config.txt file so that the fopen() function should return NULL.
What wonders me is that fopen("config.txt", "rt"); fails, but when debugging the code it just skips the "if (fptr == NULL) {...}" part and directly jumps out of the function.

When going on with the debugging process, I get the following error when trying to work with the return Value of readConfig() "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFA4E0EB70"

Comment: What is `"extendedPokeConfig.txt"`?

Comment: Where's the definition of `fptr`?  Presumably is `FILE *fptr;` or `static FILE *fptr;` or something similar, but … your code isn't an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  That makes it hard for us to help you.

Comment: @WeatherVane my bad, typo. Should be config.txt

Comment: Please post a fully copy/pasted coherent code.

Comment: Note that you should not pass string literals to `fopen()` because you should be able to report the file name in the error message, and if you use string literals, you have to write the literal value out multiple times.  The contradicts the DRY maxim: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: Are you certain it isn't returning your error string?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry i added it to my question.

Comment: `return "error reading config file: %s", strerror(errno);` isn't good code. Format specifiers are interpreted by `printf` type functions, but not in comma-separated statements.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okay so what is the better alternative to string literals? Sorry I am new to C. Just create a char variable and hand it in as an argument?

Comment: @TomKarzes no I am not. That is why I am trying to debug the code. But I am not able to get past the if (fptr == NULL) {...} line as mentioned.

Comment: @WeatherVane I get that. In my case it is a DLL where I can not write my own logs. I have to pass/return Strings to be able to log them.

Comment: Note that the `buffer` and `bufSize` function arguments will 'shadow' the global variables. Not enough information posted. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. It isn't clear what those global variables are for.

Comment: `const char filename[] = "config.txt"; FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r"); if (fp == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s': %d (%s)\n", filename, errno, strerror(errno); … }`.  Though often the filename will be an argument to the function opening the file.  But the error message should include the filename; it makes it much easier to interpret the problem (especially if you don't have the source code handy).

Comment: Just print the error message on the terminal, don't return it in place of the result.

Comment: Also, your second call to `strerror(errno)` is using the error from `fclose()`, not `fgets()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okay I will do it that way, thank you. But I expect that this will not affect/solve my problem where the fopen() function does not return NULL :/

Comment: @Barmar good advice! How can I change that? After returning I can not call fclose() anymore, or can I?

Comment: Okay I figured out that it is not about the "if (fptr == NULL)". It is about the " return "error opening config file: %s", strerror(errno);" line. When deleting the "strerror()" part the code works as intended. So I guessed I messed something up with the "strerror()" part.

Comment: You're correct that changing the way you use `fopen()` to ensure the filename is not a string literal won't affect the behaviour of the code beyond allowing you to give a better error message without having to repeat the string literal.

Comment: It's a bad idea to return the error message for errors and the file content for non-errors.  You cannot tell which is which.

Comment: @CodeEnjoyer If you print the error message instead of returning it, you can print it before calling fclose. If you want to call fclose before printing or returning the error message, save `errno` in another variable first, then call `strerror(saved_errno)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Cannot compile your code as you shared a snippet (no `main()`) and didn't include config.h.
2. `#include <string.h>` for `strerror()`.
3. Suggest caller passes in local variables instead of global variables.
4. Instead of hard-coding the size in both `buffer[50]` and `bufSize = 50;` use `sizeof` to determine the size of the array.  The other good alternative is to define a constant.
5. The `fopen()` mode "t" isn't standard, so either leave it out or tag your program with windows or whatever.
6. As you return on error, eliminate the unnecessary `else` & indentation.
7. The expression `return "error opening config file: %s", strerror(errno);` doesn't work the way you expect, it will evaluate the first part in void context then return the 2nd part `strerror(errno)`.  I was not able to otherwise reproduce any ill effects.
8. `fgets()` return NULL on eof or error but not appear to set `errno`.  You can use `feof()` and/or `ferror()` to tell which if needed.
9. After the call to `fgets()` you call `fclose()` prior to inspecting `errno`, so it have the status of the `fclose()` call instead.
10. It's a bad design to return either error message or the value you read from the file as you cannot tell them apart.  Changed to return NULL on success.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readConfig(char *buffer, size_t bufSize) {
    FILE* fptr = fopen("config.txt", "r");
    if(!fptr)
        return strerror(errno);
    if(!fgets(buffer, bufSize, fptr)) {
        fclose(fptr);
        return "fgets eof/error";
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    char b[50];
    const char *error = readConfig(b, sizeof b);
    if(error) {
        printf("error: %s\n", error);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s", b);
}
```

Consider having caller open the file and pass in the `FILE *`.  It gives you the flexibility, for instance, to use `stdin` as the file handle.

I prefer using `goto` instead of the multiple returns when resource cleanup is required.  It's a bit more verbose here but each error case is handled the same way.  When you swap the arguments you can document how they are related with recent compilers:

```
char *readConfig(size_t bufSize, char buffer[bufSize]) {
    char *r = NULL;
    FILE* fptr = fopen("config.txt", "r");
    if(!fptr) {
        r = strerror(errno);
        goto out;
    }
    if(!fgets(buffer, bufSize, fptr)) {
        r = "fgets eof/error";
        goto out;
    }
out:
    fptr && fclose(fptr);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: You can eliminate the useless `fptr &&` by using `goto out1` and `goto out2` combined with `out2: fclose(fptr); out1: return r;`

Comment: Yes, I considered it, and found the above cleaner.